# Where to get help choosing older PC games?

Tags: backwards-compatibility

I'd like to get some advice on the quality of games older than say 4 years, because my PC is quite slow by today's standards. Does anyone know some good resources for this?

Answer (score 14):

[Good Old Games](http://www.gog.com) is a great place to buy older PC games, they're all DRM-free and patched/modified to run on modern OSes. The community is also great in general, and a lot of the game reviews are very well-written. They have a new feature too that lets people set up "GOG mixes" which are basically groups of games, so if you can find one including games you already like, you'd probably like any others in the same group.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest hassle with older games tends to be a lack of widescreen monitor support by many (but not all) games from before 2004 or so.

Widescreengamingforum.com has a [list](http://www.widescreengamingforum.com/wiki/Essential_Games_List) of many older games with widescreen issues and solutions which I have found very handy.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing you can do is look for web critics who review old games (such as Spoony at spoonyexperiment.com). Amazon.com has a wide selection of old PC games listed and you can have them listed by rating, but this doesn't have the best quality. Another option is to read modern PC gaming magazines. This might seem counter-intuitive but I found that they would frequently refer to games that the writers of the articles did or didn't like and even use older games for benchmarking.

I would like to note that I haven't read many gaming magazines recently, so that might have changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also commit to [this site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20517/game-recommendations) and help it open quickly! You will then be sure it will have the well-known quality of all stackexchange sites.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call 4 years particularly old. Windows 7 was released 5 years ago, so most games since shouldn't give you too much trouble. Vista was release 9 years ago and if a game ran okay on Vista, you probably won't have too much trouble.

Old than that, Windows XP era, might call problems. Windows 98 era, will cause headaches. Before that, you could be in for a rough ride. But search the internet for help. Unless your game is *really* obscure, you'll probably find help.